# How To Tell Which Error Status Code Will be Rendered from Rails Exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

Is there a way to tell which error code will be rendered by `rail`s in production for a specific error code (e.g. `ActionController::ParameterMissing`)?

Comment: If you can't write an integration test that throws an error naturally, you can use a Mocha mock to force an error, such as `User.any_instance.stubs(:save!).raises(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`, or similar for your situation. An integration test will show you how the system behaves catching such an exception.

Comment: @Phlip I realize there _are_ ways to do it, just not convenient ones that I know of. :) It seems like there should be some way to check via documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rails source code defines these mappings for [controller exceptions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/exception_wrapper.rb#L9):

```
  "ActionController::RoutingError"                     => :not_found,
  "AbstractController::ActionNotFound"                 => :not_found,
  "ActionController::MethodNotAllowed"                 => :method_not_allowed,
  "ActionController::UnknownHttpMethod"                => :method_not_allowed,
  "ActionController::NotImplemented"                   => :not_implemented,
  "ActionController::UnknownFormat"                    => :not_acceptable,
  "ActionDispatch::Http::MimeNegotiation::InvalidType" => :not_acceptable,
  "ActionController::MissingExactTemplate"             => :not_acceptable,
  "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken"         => :unprocessable_entity,
  "ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest"        => :unprocessable_entity,
  "ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters::ParseError"       => :bad_request,
  "ActionController::BadRequest"                       => :bad_request,
  "ActionController::ParameterMissing"                 => :bad_request,
  "Rack::QueryParser::ParameterTypeError"              => :bad_request,
  "Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError"           => :bad_request
```

An these for [ActiveRecord exceptions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c4d8e057c540dd0ba424dcc5203db1c945b4b412/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L21):

```
  "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound"   => :not_found,
  "ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError" => :conflict,
  "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid"    => :unprocessable_entity,
  "ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved"   => :unprocessable_entity
```

Comment: It's worth noting that Rails also adds to this mapping in other places, so this is not the final list. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c4d8e057c540dd0ba424dcc5203db1c945b4b412/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L21